# Laravel 5 How to follow DRY in my simple controller logic?

Tags: laravel-5

I have some simple logic in my Controller. But I often use it in other method. Here is an example.

In my controller.

```
public function method1()
{
if(isset(Auth::user()->showroom->name)){
          $showroomName = Auth::user()->showroom->name;
        }else{
          $showroomName = "Belum Ada Izin";
        }
        return view('method1view', compact('showroomName'));
}

public function method2()
{
if(isset(Auth::user()->showroom->name)){
          $showroomName = Auth::user()->showroom->name;
        }else{
          $showroomName = "Belum Ada Izin";
        }
        return view('method2view', compact('showroomName'));
}
... so on
```

How I can follow DRY principle in my case?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For cleaner and shorter syntax, use `data_get` helper:

```
data_get(Auth::user(), 'showroom.name', 'your default value');
```

This in most cases comes handy, but not always is the best way.

However, in your example it seems, that maybe in fact you'd like to simply [share this variable across your views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views#sharing-data-with-all-views) - use `share` or a `View Composer` described in the docs.

Comment: Any advice where should I put `data_get()` function? so I can call in my controller like `$showroomName = dataGetShowroomName()` instead of `$showroomName = data_get(Auth::user(), 'showroom.name', 'your default value');`

Comment: Just put it where you need it. Controller is not bad, unless it's a 'global' variable - then you can register a function in, say, `app/helpers.php` file (that you will add to composer `autoload -> files` array)

Answer (score 0):

In your Showroom model you could include the following function:

```
public function getNameAttribute($value)
{
    return isset($value) ? $value : 'Belum Ada Izin';
}
```

That's assuming you want that behavior everywhere `showroom->name` is used. If not, make the function `getNameWithDefaultAttribute`, check `$this->name` in the body, and reference it in the controller like `Auth::user()->showroom->name_with_default`